# Rate Limit for users in exim

Tags: centos, exim

I tried to put a limit of sending messages, based on users who are placed in a text file, using the following ACL:

```
acl_check_limit:
deny authenticated = *
     message = Lo sentimos, ha agotado el número permitido de envíos diarios
     set acl_c_msg_limit=${lookup{$sender_address}nwildlsearch{/etc/exim/send_limits}{yes}}
     ratelimit = 100 / 1h / strict / $authenticated_id
```

But this does not work for me, only the overall limit for all users if it works properly, and can not find where the variable: $authenticated_id is initialized
Any help is welcome
thanks

Comment: I nwhich ACL did you try this? Use in **acl_smtp_rcpt** for example (or anywhere **authenticated_id** is already defined).